# click doenst work when i generated Qpushbutton

Tags: python, pyside6

when i generate buttons they don't receive click signal
how to add signal sources different for each button?
is it possible to generate buttons in a live program?
according to my idea, this code should create buttons based on the data unloaded from the database, and when you click on it, subject to the conditions, load another list and open it in one area of the window, and the full description of the structure element in another

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

def changePalette(self, MainWindow, styleName=QPalette):
    MainWindow.setPalette(styleName)


def changeStyle(self, styleName):
    ColorStyle.ColorShema().setStyle(styleName="white")


def checkedSubtusk(self,task_id, name, score):

    self.infoLeftDownbox(TaskName=name, score=score)

    self.subtaskarray = BD.select_current_subtasks(tusk_id=task_id)
    self.coordinate = 20
    if not self.subtaskarray == None:
        for self.button in self.subtaskarray:
            self.subtusk(name="test", subTuskName=self.button[1], coordinate=self.coordinate)
            self.coordinate += 30
    else:
        self.taskGroupBox.setStatusTip("What Happened?")
        print("click to me")


def tusk(self, name, taskName,task_id,score, coordinate=30, ):
    self.Tusk = QPushButton(self.taskGroupBox)
    self.Tusk.setObjectName(name)
    # self.Tusk.setEnabled(True)
    self.Tusk.setGeometry(QRect(20, coordinate, 441, 21))
    # self.Tusk.setCheckable(True)
    self.Tusk.setChecked(True)
    self.Tusk.setText(taskName)
    # self.descriptBox.setVisible(False)
    self.Tusk.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor))
    self.Tusk.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    self.Tusk.setAutoRepeat(False)
    self.Tusk.setAutoRepeatDelay(300)
    self.Tusk.setAutoDefault(True)
    self.Tusk.clicked.connect(self.checkedSubtusk(task_id, name=name,score=score))


def subtusk(self,name,subTuskName,coordinate):

    self.SubTusk = QPushButton(self.gBoxSubTask)
    self.SubTusk.setObjectName(name)
    self.SubTusk.setEnabled(True)
    self.SubTusk.setGeometry(QRect(20, coordinate, 441, 25))
    self.SubTusk.setCheckable(True)
    self.SubTusk.setChecked(True)
    self.SubTusk.setText(subTuskName)
   
    # self.descriptBox.setVisible(False)
## main block
class MyWin(QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)
    self.newTaskWindow = Ui_CreateTaskForm()UI

    
    self.ui.createTaskBtn.clicked.connect(self.openDialog) 
    
    self.ui.newTaskAction.triggered.connect(self.openDialog)
    self.ui.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.exit)
    self.datatusk = BD.select_today_tasks()
    self.coordinate = 30
    for self.button in self.datatusk:
        self.ui.tusk(name="test", taskName=self.button[1], task_id=self.button[0],score=self.button[9], coordinate=self.coordinate)
        self.coordinate += 30
    # self.ui.Tusk.clicked.connect(self.ui.checkedSubtusk(1, name="22", score=0))
```

I am uploading a list from a database and I want to make it clickable. By adding to it the ability to work with the graphic block when pressed, But the button does not react at all.
When a program starts, the condition it must fulfill is met immediately.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but your code is very confusing. Besides, you should ***not*** manually edit a uic created file. On the other hand, you're continuously overwriting the same instance attributes (`self.button`, `self.Tusk`, etc) and you're also trying to use fixed geometries (which is highly discouraged) instead of using [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html).

Comment: thanks for the tip about dynamic scaling. I am just starting to use the GUI.
I apologize for the organization of the code.
Tell me, why can't you manually edit the files generated by the ui? And about the buttons, I probably had a question. How it is possible to implement it through UI then? I need a dynamic, clickable list

Comment: I'll only answer to the first question, as the other is too broad. There're dozens of reasons for which you shouldn't edit those files, the main one is that as soon as you need to make changes to the UI, merging the new code with the existing is a mess (usually a nightmare), and that's only assuming you didn't overwrite the file by mistake, loosing everything in the process. There're lots of other reasons, but just be aware that *anybody* that has done that, believing they could ignore those reasons, sooner or later regretted that choice. And the warning on top of those file is there for that.